# Is it possible to know number of iteration of MLPClassifier?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, mlp

I tried to build a mlp classifier using GeneticSelectionCV and sklearn. I fixed the max_iter to 25000. Now I would like to know the exact number of iterations. The code I used is given below.

```
from genetic_selection import GeneticSelectionCV
import pandas as pds
import numpy as num
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

X = X_train
y = y_train



estimators = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5, random_state=1, max_iter=25000)

mlp = GeneticSelectionCV(
    estimators, cv=5, verbose=0,
    scoring="accuracy", max_features=24,
    n_population=50, crossover_proba=0.5,
    mutation_proba=0.2, n_generations=100,
    crossover_independent_proba=0.5,
    mutation_independent_proba=0.04,
    tournament_size=3, n_gen_no_change=10,
    caching=True, n_jobs=-1)

mlp = mlp.fit(X, y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As listed in [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html), the actual number of iterations the solver has run is stored in the estimator's `n_iter_` attribute.

Comment: As I am using GeneticSelectionCV, it has no n_iter_ attribute. And mlp.n_iter_ showing the following error: 'GeneticSelectionCV' object has no attribute 'n_iter_'

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://sklearn-genetic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html), `GeneticSelectionCV` stores the estimator as it's `estimator_` attribute, so the iterations should be accessible via `mlp.estimator_.n_iter_`